# Android - Registration/Login Form with mysql.php

Tags: php, android, mysql

I am new to android. I have searched so far so many websites to begin login / registration form using php , mysql in android i have got no proper sites with output. As a beginner level i need to know is there any sites which has proper output or else guys can u help me with complete coding. I would be so gratefull if i am pleased with complete coding.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: perhaps if you are new to android google android tutorials until you come to a nice tutorial that shows you how to setup an activity and emulator because you should first learn the basics.

Comment: I have joined andorid course on an institute a couple of months ago. and i am already worked in php for 2 years and noe i want to give request and response so i choose of doing registration / login form so where can i get proper code

Comment: have a look on this
http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/22/create-simple-login-form-php-android-connect-php-android/

Comment: @santhiya then dont say `I am new to android`

Comment: Thank u so much Mohammad Khatri, I got a perfect output and i learn android coding for selecting user from mysql in the link u have given http://www.coderzheaven.com/2012/04/22/create-simple-login-form-php-android-connect-php-android/

Comment: I need to learn how to insert values in mysql db using android so could you help like links u gave for selecting user Mohammad Khatri

Answer (score 0):

Your question Is not all that clear. I think of two ways you can do what you are looking for.

1. Build a real android app and pass the data via XML.
2. You create a webview (basically you are displaying a website though the app)
   In which case you use php like you would a normal site and the front end is very mobile friendly.

So either way you go you need to  google "php login tutorial"

Comment: Thanks for your reply , but actually i just want to know the android coding of inserting values to mysqldb with the help of php with async task

Answer (score 0):

You must learn about standard connection ways of this two platforms like XML and JSON. 
I recommend you to use JSON, but how?
You must use HTTPRequest functions in Android to POST your requests then from other side in PHP you must receive them in your PHP file easily with $_POST array and use it to check login data and reply the result to Android by using JSON functions like echo json_encode() and get them in Android again;

```
$username     = $_POST("username");
$upass        = $_POST("password");         
$modelResult = User::model()->login($username, $upass); // return an array
echo json_encode($result); //echo array to android
```